# Beautifulsoup extraction using for loop into table in Python 2

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

- *Platform: Python 2.7.13 on Win 7 with spyder IDE*

Please I'm totally new to both beautifulsoup and python. I am stuck at the last two lines.

Q. I want to import the details on the url below and put them in a table. That is the information with **dd** tags:

The first part of the code works well to get the link and get all the school details. However, i'm having trouble running the for command to get the remaining elements.

full code is below

```
# coding: utf-8



import urllib2
url = "http://tools.canlearn.ca/cslgs-scpse/cln-cln/rep-fit/p/af.p.clres.do?institution_id=default&searchType=ALL&searchString=&progLang=A&instType=B&prov_1=prov_1&progNameOnly=N&start=0&finish=999&section=1"
#try:
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
#except (httplib.HTTPException, httplib.IncompleteRead, urllib2.URLError):
#    missing.put(tmpurl)


import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
rooturl = "http://tools.canlearn.ca/cslgs-scpse/cln-cln/rep-fit/p/"


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup




soup = BeautifulSoup(page)




info = soup.find_all("div", class_="wb-frm")






names = [x.ol.find_all("li") for x in info][0]




def f(string):
    return str(string[0] + ', ' + string[-1])




names2 = [names[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(names), 3)]




diploma = [ [x[0].findAll("a")[0].find(text=True).strip() ,x[1].string              ,f(x[2].find(text=True).strip().split()) ] for x in names2]




links = [x.ol.find_all("a") for x in info][0]




links2 = [y.get('href') for y in links]




links3 = [rooturl + z for z in links2]

for i in xrange(len(links3)) :
    url_link = urllib2.urlopen(links3[i])
    link_html = BeautifulSoup(url_link)
#Changed the code here based on good answer given by heyiamt ..

#it was 
#    link_html2 = link_html.find_all("div", class_="wb-frm")
#    website = link_html2[0].a.get('href')
# dd[y]=link2[y].get('dd')
# diploma[i].append(dd) diploma[i].append(link_html2[0].a.get('href'))
#    diploma[i].append(website)
#Get the whole box for the general info
#    general_info_html = link_html.find_all("div", class_="panel-body")

#    general_info_html2 = [y.findAll('dd') for y in general_info_html[2:]]
#    general_info = {}
#    for x in general_info_html2 :
#      general_info.update({x[0].find(text='dt') : x[1].find(text='dd')})
#         general_info.update({x[0].get('dd')})
#    diploma[i].append(general_info)
 for d in link_html.find_all('dd'):
    if d.a is not None:
        diploma[i].append(d.a.string)
        continue

    if d.string is not None:
        diploma[i].append(d.string)
        continue

diploma[i].append(d.contents[0])

import pandas as pd


col1 = [x[1] for x in diploma]
col2 = [x[0] for x in diploma]
col3 = [x[2] for x in diploma]
col4 = [x[3] for x in diploma]
col5 = [x[4] for x in diploma]


col55 = {'Program Level' : [x.get('Program Level:') for x in col5], 'Credential Type' : [x.get('Credential Type:') for x in col5], 
    'Joint Program Level' : [x.get('Joint Program Level:') for x in col5], 
    'Joint Credential Type' : [x.get('Joint Credential Type:') for x in col5],
    'Address' : [x.get('Address:') for x in col5],
    'Telephone' : [x.get('Telephone:') for x in col5],
    'Email' : [x.get('Email:') for x in col5],
    'Fax' : [x.get('Fax:') for x in col5],
    'Toll Free' : [x.get('Toll Free:') for x in col5]
    }



df = pd.DataFrame(col1, columns = ['University'])


df2 = pd.DataFrame(col55)


df['Type'] = col2
df['City'] = col3
df['Website'] = col4
df['Address'] = df2['Address']
df['Credential Type'] = df2['Credential Type']
df['Email'] = df2['Email']
df['Fax'] = df2['Fax']
df['Joint Credential Type'] = df2['Joint Credential Type']
df['Joint Program Level'] = df2['Joint Program Level']
df['Program Level'] = df2['Program Level']
df['Telephone'] = df2['Telephone']
df['Toll Free'] = df2['Toll Free']


df.to_csv('data1.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Expected result: (i.e with "dd" tags)

http://www.rosewoodcollege.ca/program-information/

Apprenticeship Program Certificate

Not entered

Not entered

Calgary, Alberta T3J 5H3

(403) 798-7447

mail@rosewoodcollege.ca

Comment: For that page, it appears that you can count on a `dt` and `dd` pair to occur in pairs. Are you going to be able to rely on that in each of the pages you're grabbing content from?

Comment: Yes.  i can rely on that thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this site, you can just use BeautifulSoup to find the tags within the divs without actually scrolling through the divs themselves. These particular `dd` tags have a bit of fishiness to them, though. Here's a shot at managing the different possibilities.

```
# Using link_html from your code above.
dd_strs = []
for d in link_html.find_all('dd'):
    if d.a is not None:
        dd_strs.append(d.a.string)
        continue

    if d.string is not None:
        dd_strs.append(d.string)
        continue

    dd_strs.append(d.contents[0])

for dd_str in dd_strs:
    print dd_str
```

Output is

```
 http://www.rosewoodcollege.ca/program-informatio n/
Apprenticeship Program
Certificate
Not entered
Not entered
Rosewood College
(403) 798-7447
mail@rosewoodcollege.ca
2015-12-30
```

If you can rely on the `dt` tags to always be mated, in order, to the `dd` tags, you can just repeat the above but for `dt` instead of `dd` and merge the lists accordingly.

Comment: thanks it works. However, I'm working on the whole (full) code and  I don't want the last dd with the date

Comment: @insighty, sorry, i missed that detail in your desired output. a quick `dd_strs.pop()` after the for loop should drop that last string for you.